# SweetAlert combine with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have ajax delete function but it keeps cannot work with my sweetalert,i dont know what wrong with my code,can't see any place wrong.Please tell me how to modify it.

```js
function deletei(){

    swal({
      title: 'Are you sure?',
      text: 'You won\'t be able to revert this!',
      type: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
    },function ($rfno,$user) {
  theuser = $user;
     therfno = $rfno;
     
          $.ajax ({
           type: "POST",
           url: "updateleave.php",
           data: {RefNo: $rfno, userid: $user},
     success: function () {
     swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted!', 'success')
    }
     
          });
    });
  }
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="deletei(\'' .$poarr[$i]['RefNo']. '\',\''.$poarr[$i]['StaffId'].'\')" >
```

Comment: What's the value of `$poarr[$i]['RefNo']` and `$poarr[$i]['StaffId']`?

Comment: that was actually sql value,previously it works with the boostrap modal method,but now when i change to sweetalert it keep cannot pass the parameter

Answer (score 1):

So i have updated my successful answer for my current condition.Hope You guys can take a reference indeed,i did not add the library in fiddle ,so you guys may just copy this code and amend yourself.Thanks everyone who provide suggestion for me!

```js
function deletei($refnos,$users){
   
   var refId = $refnos;
   var userId = $users;
   SwalDelete(refId,userId);
   e.preventDefault();
  
 }
 
  

function SwalDelete(refId,userId){
   
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You won\'t be able to revert this!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!',
 preConfirm: function() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {  
    $.ajax ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "updateleave.php",
      data: {RefNo: refId, userid: userId},
   success: function(data){
      swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted!', 'success'); 
   var tbl = document.getElementById("myTable");
         for (var i=0; i < tbl.rows.length; i++) {
            var trs = tbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")[i];
             var cellVal=trs.cells[0].innerHTML;
              if (cellVal=== refId)  {
               document.getElementById("myTable").deleteRow(i);
           
      break; }
           }
                    },
     });
       
  });
},
});
 
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onClick="deletei(\'' .$poarr[$i]['RefNo']. '\',\''.$poarr[$i]['StaffId'].'\')" ></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

showCancelButton: true, is deprecated. I will recommend using buttons. You could then create an array with what buttons you want.

Answer (score 0):

```js
   function deletei(user,rfno){
var theuser = user;
var therfno = rfno;
swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You won\'t be able to revert this!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
},function () {
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updateleave.php",
        data: {RefNo: therfno, userid: theuser},
        success: function () {
            swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted!', 'success')
        }

    });
});
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="button" onClick="deletei(\'' .$poarr[$i]['RefNo']. '\',\''.$poarr[$i]['StaffId'].'\')" >
```

Try this .
Modification :- remove **$** from `$rfno`

Edit:-You are not passing the value of `username` and `regNo` in `deletei` function.

Comment: sweet-alert is working out side of the ajax in your page ?

Comment: yes,is working outside,it suppose be when click on the delete button,it will delete it and come out another message to alert it's succesfully done

Comment: The `$` is a valid character for JavaScript identifiers. Why should there be a difference between `$rfno` and `rfno`?

Comment: Just alert there in success and check simple alert working or not ?

Comment: is still not working sorry typo error ,the only the initial alert is pop up after click on the delete,then it doesn't proceed to executed the ajax .only dismiss it and nothing to change with my data.

Answer (score 0):

You call `deletei` with the two arguments `$poarr[$i]['RefNo']` and `$poarr[$i]['StaffId']`, but you don't use them in `deletei`. I suspect these arguments should be the value of `theuser` and `therfno`?

```js
function deletei($rfno, $user){
  swal({
    title: 'Are you sure?',
    text: 'You won\'t be able to revert this!',
    type: 'warning',
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
  }, function () {
    $.ajax ({
      type: "POST",
      url: "updateleave.php",
      data: {RefNo: $rfno, userid: $user},
      success: function () {
        swal('Deleted!', 'Your file has been deleted!', 'success')
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Is stll now working.i'm calling the $rfno and $user was used to fetch the paramenter value from the onclick function,and pass it to the function so that can post it to the php file

Comment: What exactly isn't working? Is the AJAX request not executed? I just edited my answer and changed the `data` to `data: {RefNo: $rfno, userid: $user}`.

Comment: The ajax is not working,only the sweetalert is working when click on the delete button it straight way dismiss the alert modal and do nothing for the ajax function.